# The empty path didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am very new in Django & trying to run my first project. But stucked in the error "**The empty path didn’t match any of these.**" as mentioned above. In my app urls I have the following code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path('members/',views.members,name='members'),
]
```

And in my project urls I have the following code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
path('', include('members.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I read a number of answers of this question & found suggestion that not working for me.Seeking help to dig into the error.

Here is the full error tracbac:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in my_tennis_club.urls, Django tried 
these URL patterns, in this order:

members/ [name='members']
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your 
Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display 
a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Can you share the full error tracback

Comment: Here is the full error tracback:

      Page not found (404)
      Request Method: GET
      Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
      Using the URLconf defined in my_tennis_club.urls, Django tried these URL 
      patterns, in this order:

      members/ [name='members']
      admin/
      The empty path didn’t match any of these.

      You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings 
      file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.'

@rahul.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path('members/',views.members,name='members'),
]
```

to the following:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.members,name='members'),
]
```

Comment: Would you please explain why this works.

Comment: Sure, As per your project urls, the empty path goes to the app urls. Once it reaches the app urls, there instead of empty path, you had declared "members/" that is why it was failing.

Answer (score 3):

You set your app path to `127.0.0.1:8000/members` but you are trying to request `127.0.0.1:8000/`. If you delete `members/` from your path, it will work.